# Changing from indexed=False to True in an Entity is not fetched in projection query

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a User model whose **lastname** property was not indexed. I want the lastname to be used in projection query.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
   firstname = ndb.StringProperty()
   lastname = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
   role = ndb.StringProperty()
   activated = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

Since lastname is not indexed, I cannot use this for projection queries.So,I included **lastname** in my index

```
   lastname = ndb.StringProperty()
```

For projection query(fetching lastname also) I am using the below queries:

```
users1 = User.query().filter(User.activated == True).order(User.firstname).fetch(limit=10, offset=10, projection=[User.firstname, User.role, User.lastname])
```

This query is to get the lastname in the projection query also.This query is not fetching any list of users

If I am using the below query(w/o fetching lastname) :

```
users = User.query().filter(User.activated == True).order(User.firstname).fetch(limit=10, offset=10, projection=[User.firstname, User.role])
```

This seems to be working fine and gives me the expected output.

I think this seems to be a bug in gae or does it takes a **lot** of time to update the indexes(which I don't think so).My data-set contains approx 1024 entities.
I have created a sample app on gae http://bugtestingg.appspot.com/ which demonstrates the behavior 
Here is my index.yaml file

```
indexes:
- kind: User
  properties:
  - name: activated
  - name: firstname
  - name: role
- kind: User
  properties:
  - name: activated
  - name: firstname
  - name: lastname
  - name: role
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to re-put() all those entities that is already in there.

Comment: you mean I have to re-put all my User once again?

Comment: yes, it will only cost the write for that index anyway + the query.

Comment: but why is it so? I feel GAE should handle it automatically.

Comment: It does it automatically for composite index, but if you explicitly told gae not to index a single property a composite index for unindexed property won't work. This feature is already requested and acknowledge though.

Comment: was looking for it, and found it here you go. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231